# Pressing back button in child activity-> main activity in app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm using SlidingMenu and 3/4 navigation is done by it. And if I want to go back I have to went through all these activities which I open before.
I would like to change it to such that closing any child activity (not a main activity) sends me to app main activity, and if then I press back it exit app.
Simple as that.

I open new activities that way:

```
Intent LinieActivity = new Intent(Oznaczenia.this, Linie.class);
            startActivity(LinieActivity);
```

and I have tried putting in my Manifest such thing:

```
<activity
        android:name=".childActivity"
        android:label="some name">
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Try reading this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923537/close-an-activity-from-other-activity

Comment: I solve it by using 'finish' (look below). I tried to google it and search here questions but title was hard to formulate. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you are done with an activity, you can call the command `finish();` to close that page. So I would call the next page I want to open using an intent, then after that call `finish();` and the page will close.

```
ItemPage ItemPage = new ItemPage();
Intent i = new Intent(context, ItemPage.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

When you hit the back button, none of the pages you called finish on will be there.

Comment: Thx, I hadn't thought about 'finish()'. Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is the code for back button pressed you can mange if you want to exit you can otherwise you can go to your main activity

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Exit App?")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            WelcomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }).create().show();
    }
```