# NullPointerException whn closing an Activity from another Activity

Tags: android

I have Activity A that starts another Activity B.

When I am in Activity B I should be able to close both A and B.

For this purpose I used the approach at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509279/1815311, but sometimes I get a `NullPointerException` when I do `aActivity.handleToClose.finish();`

Please what possibly can be wrong here???

Comment: `aActivity == null` or `handleToClose == null`

Comment: You might close A before starting B. Then just close B when it's time to.

Comment: @DerGolem Hi Der Golem thanks, but I want to keep Activity A for the use to navigate to if he presses BACK

Comment: @Foxinsocks Hi Fox, thanks but I am not sure I understand what you mean... :-)

Comment: @LisaAnne It's quite trivial exception and in your case it is not connected with `Activity` at all. Just use break points to solve it. I recommend you to read some Java basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because your  Activity A is closed form some reason and when you call you method to close that activity you get null pointer exception.

The solution is to check if Activity A is finished or not, if it is finished than you dont need to call finish

Comment: thanks Ultimo, I see this could be the cause, but I an not closing A, so I do not understand how possibility can it be closed... any idea? Thanks. LISA

Comment: There are 2 options: Android closes this Activity  or when you start Activity with intent you have put any flag that clears activity stack

Comment: mmmm I do not to the latter; the former: is it likely under normal circumstances? I do not think so

Comment: To check if Android System closes your activity you can debug the code, or see if it is called the onDestroy of ActivityA