# How to close an Activity when it's stopped?

Tags: android

Actually the scenario is a bit more complex than described it the title.

The situation is the following:

- Activity A starts Activity B.
- Activity A must not be destroyed when I start Activity B because I
  need the user to be able to navigate back to A.
- When the user presses the HOME button the user opens the Recent Apps
  window and switches from my app to another app. At this stage both A
  and B are STOPPED.
- When the user user opens the Recent Apps window and switches back for
  the other app to my app: Activity B is RESTARTED (activity A is not
  restarted yet)
- Now on Activity B there is a button to close the entire app, closing
  both B and A, and it does close both activities using this approach:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509279/1815311
- THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN ACTIVITY B TRIES TO CLOSE BOTH B AND A, IN
  THE DESCRIBED SCENARIO, ACTIVITY A **SOMETIMES** IS NULL !!

How do I cope with such a scenario?

Comment: Approach mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11509279/1815311 is **very-very** bad and causes activity leaks and "null pointer exceptions". Android doesn't work this way. I would strongly recommend rethinking your app navigation. This is a good start - http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/index.html

Comment: Have you considered using _startActivityForResult_ to start Activity B. And return such a code back to Activity A it knows to call _finish()_ on itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 solution is - before finishing the activity B, store some variable with value 1 using sharedpreferences, finish activity B but not A. system will resume activity A. override onResume() function in activity A and get the variable from shared preferences, if it states 1 then store 0 there, and finish() activity A.

2 solution is overriding onresultactivity - see here

[How to kill an application with all its activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/android-how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities)